# SQL Statement to find between two table less than date

Tags: sql

I'm stuck trying to find sql statement... I am using

```
SELECT rank.rank_name FROM rank, promotion_log
WHERE rank.Id=promotion_log.rank 
AND (promotion_date<=@PD AND promotion_log.employee_ID=@ID)
```

I am trying to find rank name of employee where their most recent promotional date is less than or equal to a given date. This way I can have logs written and be able to retrieve them with the rank of employee at that time. Above statement is just returning most recent rank.

Comment: provide sample data and desired output. also tag your dbms

Comment: Please don't spam tags. This has got exactly nothing to do with VB.NET. This is purely a SQL question and the language used to write the application that executes that SQL is completely irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to do this (SQL SERVER syntax):

```
SELECT TOP 1 rank.rank_name 
FROM rank JOIN promotion_log  
ON rank.Id=promotion_log.rank 
AND (promotion_date<=@PD AND promotion_log.employee_ID=@ID)
ORDER BY promotion_date desc
```